# Compose TextField automaticly wrapped text not treated as new line

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am looking for a valid solution for counting lines in `TextField`. I know there is `maxLines` parameter, I know I can split the text by "\n" and count it. But the problem is that when the text is wrapped automatically, its not treated as the new line. And because of that I can actually write as many words as I wish and the number of lines can exceed `maxLines`.

So current approach does not work.

```kotlin
            BasicTextField(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .onFocusChanged {
                        isFocused = it.isFocused
                    },
                value = textState,
                onValueChange = {
                    onTextChanged(it.text)
                    if (it.text.split("\n").size <= maxLines) {
                        textState = it
                    }
                },
                maxLines = maxLines
            ) { innerTextField -> }
```

Non-elegant solution is to count the width of the `TextField`, figure out the font size, divide it to get more less the maximum of characters in one line, but... c'mon...

Is there any official / valid solution for preventing the `TextField` from exceeding the maximum lines respecting the wrapping of the text ?

Answer (score 0):

it's acutually easy if you know how to use the parameter `onTextLayout` all you have to do is this:

```
BasicTextField(
      modifier = Modifier
      .fillMaxWidth()
      .onFocusChanged {
          isFocused = it.isFocused
      },
      value = textState,
      onValueChange = {
      onTextChanged(it.text)
      if (it.text.split("\n").size <= maxLines) {
            textState = it
      }
      },
       maxLines = maxLines,
       onTextLayout = {
          lineCount = it.lineCount
      }
      ) { innerTextField -> }
```

now you can use this `lineCount` variable in anything you want.

Comment: Thx for the answer. What does it mean “use it in anything you want”. How to consume this to prevent from exceeding maxLines? This information about lineCount is just a variable.

Comment: @P.Juni well I mean if you see in the `onTextLayout` I associated the `it.lineCount` to a variable named `lineCount` and this can be used for anything that requires it. for exemple to use it to prevent from execeding maxLines you can simply add a condition in the `onValueChange` like : `if(lineCount<= maxLines) text = it` . something like this will do the job

Comment: Thx for the answer, but it does not solve the problem unfortunately. I can easily write more lines even with this check since wrapping of the text is not considered as new line